# can't extend react extended class

Tags: reactjs, oop

I have more than 20 components in my react project. So doing the same thing for every component would be so unwise, so from oop concepts if I create a class with all the functionalities, then I can use it for all the objects I want.

In my case, I want to check if a user is logged in or not. If not redirect to '/login'. Now I have 'NavigationBar' inside each component, where I'm writing some code to redirect or not. But for a few seconds I can see then snap of each components, especially those large ones.

*This is not also wise step*

So here is what I tried next, created a component named Core extending React.Component, then I extended all component from it, but it gives me error directly.

What is the actual problem here? How this can be solved?

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-sunset-8pegp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Don’t link to external code, put the relevant code as a snippet in the question instead. Regarding extending React components, I recommend you follow React’s own advice to use composition over inheritance: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: @Lennholm I checked it out, and it's always nice to learn something new and it's awesome, while I'm learning this why don't you checkout the accepted answer it's awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this line to `Child.js`

```
import React from "react";
```

Comment: i don't know why, but this works.. and it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-sunset-8pegp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), anyone can check the console that it's working ...

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't allow creation of component by subclassing defined component, the only way to create component is to extends directly the React.Component class, But react allow you to add extra behavior to defined component by using Higher-Order Components which has purpose to alter defined component by adding wrapper to and existing component

```
function wrapper(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {

        render() {
            // Here you can add any logic you want 


            return (<div>
                // Here you can add extra code
                <h1>Code rendered by wapper</h1>
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

And you use it like this

```
import wrapper from './wrapper';
import Child from './Child';

const HigherWrapper = wrapper(Child);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<HigherWrapper />, rootElement);
```